# getting started with rqt_plot

Tags: ros-indigo, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rostopic echo is telling me there is a topic gathering data

when I use the exact same topic name  I get a message that "header" is non-numeric.  Now on the command line display I see  the 'value: " and the topic being updated.  So I don't know the magic way to name the topic so rqt_plot can magically chop the title information and just get the data.  I've tied various forms of appending the 'field" name to the topic without success.

BTW this is on indigo, Ubuntu 14.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/183013/getting-started-with-rqt_plot/) by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 147 on 2014-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK I figured it out -just add the variable name to the end of the node:  if the variable was "range:"  the full cli command would be like this:

rqt_plot /arduino/sensor/ir_front_center/range  worked fine in both hydro and indigo.

rostopic /arduino/sensor/ir_front_center  will reveal the variable of interest.

---

Originally posted by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) with karma: 147 on 2014-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on 2014-08-26**:
If running on multiple hosts you need to sync the time with chrony or use a common network derived time.